# What is the scientific argument for why SSRI’s are not available over the counter?

Tags: medication

For what specific reason is it legally required that a doctor “prescribe” you an SSRI, as opposed to the compound being available to sell and purchase freely?

Comment: Availability of drugs as prescriptions or OTC is a legal and regulatory decision, not necessarily a scientific one.

Comment: Ignorant usage may cause death.

Comment: I think the main reason is the use of insurance is for scripts only. There is a liability and the patient is responsible for their own health with the doctor's support.

Comment: As per you other question - adding research efforts can focus the question better; for instance, why wouldn't and shouldn't other psychoactive compounds not be sold over the counter like fentanyl and other opiates (yeah, the situation in some states in the US are an exception)?